# R: How do I use lag comand with a matrix several times?

Tags: r, matrix

I am using a matrix (3520 * 10) which represents the daily observations of my 10 variables. My objective is to obtain 30 matrices formed by my lagged variables that can be defined as:

[image]

Where p is the lag order, in my case `p= 1:30`. Then, my first matrix will be formed by the first lag of my ten variables and the size will be (3490*10), the second matrix will be formed by the second lag of my ten variables, and so on.

`Matrix<-matrix[1:35200, ncol=10]`

For explaining better my point I am going to use  the following matrix:

[image]

In this case, p will be 3. It means that I will use the three first observations for constructing the new matrices. For example, the matrix which contains the lagged variables when `p = 1` will be:

[image]

For `p = 2`

[image]

For `p = 3`

[image]

I was trying to use the `lag` command, but it does not function for matrices. Someone can recommend another command for this task.

Comment: What does  the lag mean? Can you use a smaller matrix to explain what you want?

Comment: @DarrenTsai I edited my original post for explaining better this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a df. Perform the `lag`. Convert back to matrices. Perhaps like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

mat <- matrix(1:64, nrow = 8)
p <- 3 # number of lags
m <- 5 # values to include
mat_df <- as.data.frame(mat)
# Step 1: Lagged by values by mapping over 1:p
mat_lag <- map(1:p, ~ mutate_all(mat_df, lag, .x)) %>% 
  # Step 2: Drop rows with missing
  map(drop_na) %>% 
  # Step 3: Now slice. Only m values starting from the last row are kept
  map(~ slice(.x, (nrow(.x) - m + 1):nrow(.x)))
# Step 4: Convert to list of matrices
mat_lag %>% 
  map(as.matrix)
#> [[1]]
#>      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
#> [1,]  3 11 19 27 35 43 51 59
#> [2,]  4 12 20 28 36 44 52 60
#> [3,]  5 13 21 29 37 45 53 61
#> [4,]  6 14 22 30 38 46 54 62
#> [5,]  7 15 23 31 39 47 55 63
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
#> [1,]  2 10 18 26 34 42 50 58
#> [2,]  3 11 19 27 35 43 51 59
#> [3,]  4 12 20 28 36 44 52 60
#> [4,]  5 13 21 29 37 45 53 61
#> [5,]  6 14 22 30 38 46 54 62
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
#> [1,]  1  9 17 25 33 41 49 57
#> [2,]  2 10 18 26 34 42 50 58
#> [3,]  3 11 19 27 35 43 51 59
#> [4,]  4 12 20 28 36 44 52 60
#> [5,]  5 13 21 29 37 45 53 61
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I edited my original post in order to improve my explanation of the problem

Comment: Hi Eve. I just edited and revised my code, adjusted the example data to a 8x8 matrix, .... The first column of my example data is the same as in your 8 x 8 example. As you can see by comparing the first columns of the resulting matrices are the same as for the lagged matrices you are looking for.